# import sql file to sqlite database

Tags: php, sqlite, pdo

Maybe there is similar question, but I didn't find one writed in php.

I have a sql file and I want to import it in sqlite db.

```
$database = new PDO( 'sqlite:'.$tempdb );

if( $database->exec( $sql ) === false )
{
    die( print_r( $database->errorInfo(), true ) );
}
```

SQL Example:

```
INSERT INTO table (id,title) VALUES
(1,'title 1'), 
(2,'title 2'),
(3, 'more title');
```

Returns:

```
Array ( [0] => HY000 [1] => 1 [2] => near ",": syntax error )
```

The problem appears to be the fact of sqlite uses `PDO::bindParams()` for insert.

There is any workaround it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`table` is a keyword; you would have to quote it as `"table"`.

But assuming that you actual table name is different: Inserting multiple records with one `INSERT` command is supported only since SQLite 3.7.11; it's likely that PHP's built-in SQLite is older.

Comment: Yes, I found the problem is multiple insertions.